# Receber POST de um Json em PHP

Tags: php, json, post, http-request, request

Estou tentando receber no PHP um Json via POST e exibir ele na tela, o Json é enviado atravé de uma API que não tenho acesso ao script que envia, estou tentando a princípio imprimir na tela tudo que receber para depois dar prosseguimento, sei que é enviado através do método POST e Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Mas sempre retorna o erro "Unexpected 'A'".

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, como o dado recebido é em Json ele não vem através do POST e sim no 'php://input'

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

$dados = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $dados;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eae Daniel tudo bem? Tenta trocar a função 'header' por 'require_once', e também quando vc recebe algo q esta vindo em JSON vc deve usar o codigo "json_decode" pois ele vai desmembrar estes dados que estao vindo para vc setar eles onde vc quiser.
Assim por exemplo:

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
```

Espero que eu tenha ajudado! Valeu

Comment: Victor obrigado pela ajuda mas também não deu certo assim, consegui encontrar a solução e postei abaixo.